# How to make slide in slide out transitions in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, transition

I want to make slide in - slide out transition in windows phone 7 app, however i want to keep context of my page seen as animation progresses, i tried using Windows Phone Toolkit, but each time animation is played, page goes to black and from black, making my application (which background is green) seem flashing with black screen. The second problem that happened to me while i was trying do same with storyboard animation was that animation made with that was quite slow and laggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the wp7 toolkit from here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034

And use the page transitions.

Thereafter add these code in your xaml:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeIn"/>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeIn"/>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
</toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
<toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeOut"/>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeOut"/>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
</toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Have a look over [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide)

Comment: As i said before :) "i tried using Windows Phone Toolkit, but each time animation is played, page goes to black and from black". (I even used same tutorial as u suggested)

Comment: I don't think you can change that color as it's there by default.